# How can I set leading zeros in AssemblyVersion like "2.03.406.2" in .net

Tags: c#, .net, versioning

just adding a zero like below

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.03.406.2")]
```

results in 2.3.406.2

which is not what I want.

So this may not be possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each portion of the assembly version is stored as a 16-bit integer, so no, it's not possible.

Comment: doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can read AssemblyFileVersionAttribute

```
AssemblyFileVersionAttribute[] attributes = (AssemblyFileVersionAttribute[])typeof(Program)
    .Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false);
Console.WriteLine(attributes[0].Version);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each number represents a specific **numerical** value, Major, Minor, Build and Revision.

It isn't just an arbitary string.